# Simulating pressing of 'Page up' key in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

Is there any way by which we can simulate the pressing of 'Home' and 'Page up' key in shell script  ?
i.e. Running that script should have/cause the same effect which is caused by pressing 'Page Up' key

Comment: Can you explain where this problem is coming from? Because this is a little...weird and maybe there's a better solution if we back up a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous page: `tput kpp`, Home: `tput home`.

Now, you'll need to send these to the program you're trying to interact with. `expect` is quite useful for this.